# Apply check on tableViewCells to hide imageView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uibutton, xcode6.0.1

> In my `tableView`, I have 5 `tableView` `cells`. Each has an `imageView`.
>   Outside `tableView`, there's a `UIButton`. `UIButton` also has image on it.
>   Now, my issue is to check if the image on `cells` is hidden or not.
>   Clearing the issue, I need to check for all the cells that if
>   `imageView` on all the `cells` is hidden or not. I tried this code :

```
 for (int i=0; i<=4; i++) 
    {
     if (cell.unlockImageView.hidden)
     {
        NSLog(@"calling if for hiding image");
      }
    }
```

> I don't think my code is correct but I gave it a try and it didn't
>   work. So please suggest me  how to check that imageView on all cells
>   is hidden or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code hope it can help you.

```
for (customTableViewCell* tblCell in tableView.visibleCells)
    {
        if (tblCell.unlockImageView.hidden)
        {
            NSLog(@"Imageview is hidden");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but It didn't work. ImageView is hidden on all cells But it didn't print "Imageview is hidden" in log.

Comment: If you NSLog(@"%@",tblCell.unlockImageView) before if condition then you will get all info in log

Comment: This is the code I'm trying in app, `for (SayMoreTableViewCell* tblCell in tableView.visibleCells)
    {
         NSLog(@"Imageview is hidden %@",tblCell.ulockImageView);
        if (tblCell.ulockImageView.hidden)
        {
            
        }
    }` 
It is not calling for loop too.

Comment: what are you getting in NSLog() ?

Comment: it is printing like  0x797a7050; frame = (0 0; 320 519); hidden = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x797a70c0>>

Comment: Nothing. for loop is not getting called. If I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65202/discussion-between-pandey-laxman-and-sushil).